# Cannot use native plugins in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am having a hard time dealing with an error. I am using ionic 3 with the `File Chooser`, `File Opener`, `File Path` plugins. But the moment I install them and run the command `ionic cordova build android` i get this error https://pastebin.com/raw/Vb1sFrDk

My ionic app is a fresh app with just those 3 plugins installed. Here is my ionic info: https://pastebin.com/raw/Aixze7N2

Can someone help please?

Comment: Do you have Android Studio and Android installed?

Comment: Yes, if i do not use those 3 plugins then i can see my app in the android emulator

Comment: Try to add them one by one, to find out what plugin is the problem

Comment: ok it looks like it works on my android device (connected through usb) but gives the aforementioned error when i try to run on emulator. I am using "Pixel 2 XL" emulator. What could be the problem with emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1- Go to the plugins/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/plugin.xml

and then replace

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />
```

To

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+" />
```

2- Remove android platform :

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

3 - Add again android platform

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

4- Build your app

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```